# What is UIRectFill() in Monotouch?

Tags: uikit, xamarin.ios

In a couple of ObjC projects in the overloaded drawRect: methods I have seen `UIRectFill()` being used. What is it doing and what is the equivalent of it in Monotouch?

For instance here, where is it putting the filled rectangle to/wher is it drawing it to:

```
CGRect borderRect = bounds;
UIRectFill(borderRect);
borderRect.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(bounds) - borderThickness;
UIRectFill(borderRect);
```

Comment: Do you have an example of such a project online?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for `UIKit.UIGraphics.RectFill`.

Comment: Hm, okay, sounds reasonable. Meanwhile I found this: UIBezierPath.FromRect(borderRect).Fill (); - what's that then?

Comment: That's using a UIBezierPath, not RectangleF (or CGRect).

Answer (score 2):

You can use miguel de icaza's [Rosetta Stone](http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html) to find out the mappings between objective-c selectors and monotouch methods.

I also find the [monotouch API documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/api) very useful although there is no direct mapping between functions and selectors.

Comment: I know the Rosetta stone, but UIRectFill is not on it.